# Why does PopupWindowAction class sustain modal mode poorly for dialogs in Prism 6?

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, prism

I use PopupWindowAction class for creation of modal dialog windows (customized and predefined) in my Prism 6 WPF modular application with Unity. (I have Windows 10 on my computer and use MS VS 2015 Professional as development environment.) This is for customized modal dialog:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding LoginConfirmationRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
         <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
              <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                    <views:LoginView />
              </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Where LoginView is Prism UserControl(WPF) used for representation of login dialog content. XAML below is for predefined dialog:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding NotificationRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
        <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True"/>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

But there is a problem: When dialog (indifferently customized or predefined but with IsModal="True" property of PopupWindowAction) is displayed atop Shell and I begin (in order to verify that dialog is modal) perform frequent clicks by left mouse button on Shell area around the dialog **then the dialog is going to background and Shell is displaying atop of the dialog**. I just notice it not only in my application but also in InteractivityQuickstart example application. Why is this happening? How to set strong modality for customized and predefined dialogs? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in the latest Pre-release, and the fix will be made available with the next RTM release of Prism 6.2

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/wiki/Release-Notes--Jan-10,-2016#prism-for-wpf-611-pre2

The issue was that the window owner was never being set.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to use pre-release of Prism 6.2. But when will Prism 6.2 stable version be available?

Comment: Please tell me if in Prism 6.2 for WPF I will be able to make predifined or customized modal or non-modal dialog have unchangeable size and remove 'Minimize', 'Zoom' and 'Close' buttons that are in right upper corner of the dialog?

Comment: Yes. Although you can do that now, it will be easier in 6.2

Comment: How can I remove  'Minimize', 'Zoom' and 'Close' buttons that are in right upper corner of the dialog and make the dialog have unchangeable size in Prism 6.1.0 ? Or it is possible only in pre-release not in stable version?

Comment: Right now you have to create your own PopupWindowAction to do that. In 6.2 you will be able to use simple properties.

Comment: OK, so I must inherit my own class from PopupWindowAction or make changes to now existing PopupWindowAction?

Comment: How soon Prism 6.2 for WPF stable release is assumed to appear? I write production-level app so that using of pre-release of Prism library is risky for me.